# Current Time in millisecond

Tags: java, mysql

I am writing a stored procedure in mysql and want to insert system's current timestamp into millisecond format. is there utilities or function which can give time in millisecond what java's system.currentimeinmillisecond do.

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
+------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP() |
+------------------+
|       1392786039 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: it does not give exactly milisecond. it gives second and if we multiply by 1000 it does not give exact milliseocnd format what we get for system.currenttimeinmillisecond()

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) which explains the use of

```
SELECT MICROSECOND('2010-12-10 14:12:09.019473');
```

as MySQL 5.6.4 and up expands fractional seconds support for TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision

Comment: what does `MICROSECOND` return? time in milliseconds?

Comment: @NandkumarTekale as per my answer, it allows for microseconds (6 digits) precision.  Easy enough to convert (divide) to get milliseconds.  But if you have only seconds, you can not get millisecond precision